# Problems with CURL function matlab

Tags: matlab

My question is related to the curl of a vector field . I can not find why my code throws different results when compared with the analytical solution . I appreciate any help to the question.

this is the code:

```
N=20;
[X,Y]=meshgrid(linspace(-4,4,N),linspace(-4,4,N)); 
u =Y*X.^2+3*Y.^2;
v =2*X.*Y+X.^2;
% analitic curl
CURL=-X.^2+2*X-4*Y;
subplot(2,1,1),contourf(X,Y,CURL),colorbar
% using  matlab function (curl)
[cur,va]=curl(X,Y,u,v);
subplot(2,1,2),contourf(X,Y,cur),colorbar
```

Comment: Removed the `curl` tag from your post.  The tag you used refers to the terminal command `curl`... not the actual MATLAB function.  Removed this to avoid confusion.

Comment: MATLAB has to numerically approximate any solutions, whilst the analytical solutions directly takes the derivative into account. See e.g. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32570306/numerically-compute-derivative-of-complex-valued-function-in-matlab) post on complex derivatives.

Comment: I calculated the curl using the following formula: Vx-Uy nd gives me the following: -X^2+2X-4Y.   I'm interested in comparing the numerical solution with the analytical . But these equations the numerical result is far from the analytical solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you have

```
u =Y*X.^2+3*Y.^2;
```

Which is a problem: you apply a **matrix** multiplication between `Y` and `X.^2`. Changing it should help a lot:

```
u =Y.*X.^2+3*Y.^2;
```

For this reason I suggest using asymmetric inputs (at least for the development/debug stage), such as a 20x21 mesh. This way many such errors can be caught early on.

Result:
[image: fixed curl figure]

Comment: Thanks @AndrasDeak !!